How to Generate a Cumulative Sum of 300,000,000 Random 1s and -1s
I am trying to find an efficient way to generate a cumulative sum of 300,000,000 random 1s and -1s in Python. I have been able to use the solution below with n up to about 30,000,000. But if I try larger numbers I run into memory problems.
"np.cumsum" (in the function) returns an array of size n, containing all the intermediate steps. Which I use to create a random walk with Matplotlib.
def tosses(n):
    return np.cumsum(np.random.choice([-1,1],n))


Simply generate a random int in range -300,000,000 ... 300,000,000. Work smart not hard.

@Bohdan: different distribution

Sir, the Central Limit Theorem would like a word with you, please. Right this way.

Just to be clear — you are trying to create an array of 300 million integers, right?  Have you calculated how much ram that will take to keep in memory? Is there a way you can solve your problem without having the entire array in memory?

Expanding on @Mark’s comment, do you actually need the array of outcomes or do you just need the sum?

I would like to have the whole array of outcomes, not just the sum.

@IBERGUS in that case, please update your post. Why do you need all the outcomes ? How will you use them ?

I seriously doubt you’d have the resolution to see details of a 1-d random walk involving 3E8 steps.

The answers already given below are rather pointless. Your question hinges on why you need the cumsum-array (instead of just the final value), and why you need to have the whole array in memory. If you actually don't, you can use a generator. If you only need the final outcome, remember that the final sum will be a pick normally distributed around 0. You can use a random number generator to pick that value without going through the whole calculation, possibly making the problem mute.

@IBERGUS It's is even more likely that matplotlib will crash with 300 millions points.

@user2722968 mute=speechless, moot=irrelevant

As written np.choice creates the large array, and passes it to cumsum.  Distiguish between a memory error in the 2 steps.

What is the purpose of plotting this amount data ? What is the added value of 300M over, say, 300k ?

If you want the sum but don't actually need all 3E8 values, then the simplest approach is to scale a binomial distribution. A binomial random variable X is the sum of n outcomes having values 0/1, where 1 occurs with probability p and 0 occurs with probability 1-p. Since you're generating ±1's, all that's needed is to scale the outcome as Y = 2X - n.
import random

def tosses(n):
    return 2 * random.binomialvariate(n) - n

You can quickly confirm this gives the correct behavior that the result is even for even n and odd for odd n by running it for small values of n. Also, this gives correct distributional behavior for small n where using a normal approximation could yield invalid results.
I'm aware that you've said you want the entire array of outcomes, but I've written this up anyway because I agree with comments indicating that doesn't seem like a reasonable choice for n-values such as 3E8.

actually trivial to keep all samples - use one byte for a sample

@SeverinPappadeux Since OP wants to store all the values to generate a cumulative sum to plot the paths, the running tallies will quickly exceed a byte. But mainly, my biggest objection as stated in comments is that Matplotlib isn't going to give useful plots with that volume of data.

I checked wrt cumsum and updated my answer, still looks manageable for nowadays systems. Updated my answer. I agree, Matplotlib won't produce anything useful, didn't do it for me.

@SeverinPappadeux Got it, thanks. With your contribution OP should be able to avoid running out of memory. I'm still totally on board with Alicia's comment "What is the added value of 300M over, say, 300k ?".

You  are running into memory problem because you are filling an array with 300 millions int elements (9.6GB !).
You can get the same result without the array.
from random import *

def tosses(n):
    sum = 0
    for i in range (0,n):
        sum += -1.0 if randint(0,1) == 0 else 1.0
    return sum

You won't have memory problem but it is still slow.
To go further you can write a c++ equivalent and call it from python.
Since you want to plot the steps, 300M data points is very big and you won't see most of the points but a trend, and likely you will run into other memory problems, so I suggest that you store in an array for plotting only the points that you will display (eg., every 100k points to get 3k points to plot from 300M actual steps); this way you are downscaling the graph upfront. Even with 3k points you get a lot of details.

Curious why you've made this function return a float rather than an integer?

@Mark You are right it's not useful, a part of me thought about sum of a float in the range [-1.0,1.0].

Honestly, once n gets large this is identical to sampling from a normal distribution with a mean of 0 and standard deviation of the square root of n. If the sum is all one wants, it makes a lot more sense to just do np.random.normal(0, n ** .5).

Yes, @pjs that's correct about the even/odd and integers. Running the actual simulation with a large n, my std is actually ~sqrt(n) every time.

@pjs help me understand what I'm doing wrong that leads to this giving a std very close to sqrt(n) for large values of n np.random.choice([-1, 1], [samples, n]).sum(axis=1).std()

I suspect the issue is that you are missing a step: Y=2X - 1 is correct, but the variance is actually 4npq because Var(a*X+b)=a**2Var(X) because of the variance under linear transformation rule. This leads to a variance of n. But I'm admittedly a little rusty here.

@Mark You’re correct! I forgot to square the multiplicative constant! Thanks for pointing that out. This is why I shouldn’t trust my results unless they’re done on my handy white board.

I appreciate the refresher @pjs...it's been a while for me.

@Alicia I like the addendum to sample the output rather than trying to store it all. Good advice.

@pjs Thanks. I came back to this and I thought that just picking one point pediodically is actually not the desired estimator, instead an arithmetic mean of a section to reduce to a point would be better, but then we would have a double data (unless we round it). This is actually a downsampling algorithm to choose, so it may not be that important. Now I question if picking a point periodically is such a bad estimator for a stochastic process; I also wonder if bootstrapping mean of section, use the generated histogram with color intensities can be good for plotting the equivalent of a section.

You can break your array into smaller chunks. Create a for loop that iterates from 0 to n in steps of chunk_size. Within this loop, generate the array chunk as follows:
chunk = np.random.choice([-1, 1], min(chunk_size, n - i))

Then, compute the cumulative sum (cumsum) for each chunk and add the results to your output array.
This is not the only method. You can also use Memory-Mapped Files to handle large arrays without loading them entirely into memory.

use one byte for sample, that's the solution

Here is simple answer, use one byte for 1 or -1, you don't need chunks etc
rng = np.random.default_rng()
q = rng.choice([np.int8(-1),np.int8(1)], 300_000_000)
len(q)
q.nbytes

prints
300000000
300000000

@pjs stated that np.cumsum will require wider data type, which is true. By default it uses int, still manageable I would say
c = np.cumsum(q)
c.nbytes

prints
1200000000

So total ~1.5Gb, manageable on 8Gb or larger memory system. Plot likely to be garbage.
UPDATE
You could even try to use bits array for samples, and int8/int16 for cumsum, but that would likely to be very slow.

Hmm.  Better than my previous answer.
n = 300_000_000
heads = np.random.binomial(n, .5)
return 2 * heads - n.

This function is guaranteed to return an integer.

If you toss a coin n times, you can expect n/2 heads with a standard deviation of 1 / (2 sqrt(n)).
n = 300_000_000
heads = random.normal(loc=n/2, scale=1/(2 * sqrt(n)))
return 2 * heads - n # heads=+1, tails=-1

If you just round it to an integer, no one will be able to tell that you didn't actually count out 300_000_000 items.

For even n the outcome must be even, so a careful observer could tell about half the time that you didn’t actually count.

@pjs 2* heads - n will always be even for an even n

@OskarHofmann Not unless you round the normal before doing the scaling.

@pjs, @oskarhofmann.  Yes, I should have said to round first.  Then the result will always have the same parity as n.

This is a bit based answer.  It gives the cumsum to every 8th sample i.e. 37.5M points in 300M
import numpy as np

score_lu = np.zeros( 256, dtype = np.int8 )

# Initialise score_lu to number of bits set less number not set in the int8
# This arr returns the number of bits set - the number of bits not set
# for each of the 256 uint8 bit patterns.  
score_lu[ 0 ] = -8 # All bits clear
i = 1
while(i<256):
    for j in range( i, i+i ):
        score_lu[j] = score_lu[ j-i ]+2  
        # Each bit set increases the score by 2 ( an extra 1 and one fewer -1 )
    i *= 2

def sample_run( limit ):
    global arr, score # for debugging/review
    nbytes = ( limit + 7 ) // 8
    arr = np.random.randint( 256, size = nbytes, dtype = np.uint8 )
    # arr holds nbytes random bytes
    score = score_lu[ arr ] # Lookup the score for the uint8
    return score.cumsum()

np.random.seed( 12345 ) # Remove, included to reproduce the results

result = sample_run(100)
print( result )  
# [ 0 -2  4  8 10 10 10 12 12 18 24 20 16]

result = sample_run(300_000_000)
print( result )
# [   -2    -2    -4 ... -2064 -2060 -2058]

The sample_run function would need some fiddling with the last byte in arr if limit doesn't divide evenly by 8 and the precise number of bits sampled really mattered.
